# Restore keyboard character mapping

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am a new Ubuntu user. Today my keyboard character mapping has changed all on a sudden.

The following keys has been changed to give the number after the arrow:

- <kbd>J</kbd> -> 1
- <kbd>K</kbd> -> 2
- <kbd>L</kbd> -> 3
- <kbd>U</kbd> -> 4
- <kbd>I</kbd> -> 5
- <kbd>O</kbd> -> 6

I have tried to restore to default settings but same result.

My keyboard layout is English (US). How to get rid of this weird situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't installed anything or changed some keyboard configuration, you probably just enabled NumLock. At least on my system, the keys you refer are mapped to the correct numbers.

So check in your keyboard where you can disable it. If you are using a laptop, this should be something like <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>oher key</kbd> (in my Asus laptop, it is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>).